# Literal name does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Ive been running into a problem for a schoolproject and I can't get my head around it... (used to java, new to C# / ASP.NET). I've searched far and wide but nothing that helped me so far...

I just want to query data from my MySql database and show this data using Literate's on my `.aspx` page. The error message would make me think this is a scope-issue and / or I just defined something at the wrong time/place...

However, I have tried defining both the prijs & naam Literate at the main class itself it throws an error:

> CS0102: The type 'ProductDetails' already contains a definition for 'naam'

and besides, wouldnt using the `<asp:Literal>` tag on the `.aspx` page already define it from the start?

**ProductDetails.aspx**

```
<asp:Literal ID="prijs" runat="server" />
<asp:Literal ID="naam" runat="server" />
```

**ProductDetails.aspx.cs**

```
    private void getProdDetails()
    {
        connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webshopConnString"].ToString();
        queryStr = "SELECT * FROM inf_c_13026984.product WHERE productID=1";

        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
        cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                prijs.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                naam.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Many, many thanks for any help/advice/pointers in advance!!!!

Comment: When you try to define the literals in CodeBehind, you get the already defined error - but when not, you're getting: "prijs does not exist in the current context"?

Comment: Pretty sure we can't see the issue with what you are showing now. Been awhile since I used .aspx defaults but "naam" is likely defined already. You said you added the tag to the .aspx file, it would have added the member definition automatically to the generated portion of the .cs file. If you added your own "naam" member, it'll throw a compile error.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky exactly that!

Comment: @Kenny - are you still having the issue?  If so, where are you calling the function getProductDetails() from?